# How do the Armour and Weapon mustering out benefits work?

Tags: character-creation, traveller

I'm evaluating **Mongoose Traveller** as an option for a new gaming group, and currently I'm running through the character creation process.

The range of options for the Armour and Weapon mustering out benefits seems odd. For example, why would anyone pick anything but combat armour for the armour benefit?  Why not always pick the most powerful weapons?  Is this supposed to be determined by tech level, or are the characters intended to pay for these weapons somehow, or maybe the selection is just meant to be roleplayed?

Comment: @GMJoe That sounds like an almost-answer in comments that'll be deleted soon, and lost if you don't make it an actual one.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs It's not an answer. I thought that my experience might add some useful extra context to the question, though. If it's less useful than I'd hoped, I'm fine with it being deleted. Thanks for the warning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Law level is naturally a concern, but so are available skills (not everyone has the skills for Combat Armor or plasma guns) and physical stats (encumberance, strength to counteract heft, etc.) Most worlds with any appreciable law level (say, 5+) will take a dim view of people walking around in military grade armor. Even if they are not technically breaking any laws, they're certainly up to no good, from a law enforcement perspective.

And of course you should choose a mustering out weapon or armor that matches your skills. Your Referee might also restrict what hardware you can choose based off of your service, the local Tech Level (for planet-bound careers), or other factors.

My suggestion is to make the Armor be at best Combat Armor (and then only for Marines), and usually Cloth or similar. Much like the way that mustering out with a ship gives you a bare-bones, un-paid for ship, Weapons should also be "stock". If players want more extras, that's why they have money.

Historically under the original Traveller rules, the choices were more clear-cut, since different weapons had Dexterity cutoffs to avoid penalties or gain bonuses when shooting, and the same for strength and melee weapons. Players would scan the weapon list when they rolled a combat skill and pick the choice that best matched their character's stats. If you mustered out with a gun, you'd pick the one that matched your skill. People didn't muster out with armor.

Answer (score 4):

The main limitations on that sort of thing seem to come from Law Levels.  There just aren't that many places outside of your own ship where you're allowed to carry an FGMP, and you probably don't want to carry it on your ship, either.  Even combat armor is illegal on many worlds.